# Manage available network but no Internet connection

Tags: android, connection

Before performing any operation on the network I check if there is an internet connection, by this class:

```
public final class Internet {

    public static boolean online(Context context) {
        ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager)
                context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo activeNetwork = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        return activeNetwork != null && activeNetwork.isConnected();
    }

}
```

then in an activity (before performing any operation):

```
if(Internet.online) {
    /* cast my spell */
}
```

and everything works fine, BUT if there's a connection but for some reason Internet isn't REALLY available, the app crash.

How I can manage this situation? What's the best practices?

Maybe I need to check if a service (eg. Google) is reachable? Or I need to use (inside the 'if' statement) some try/catch (if yes, with witch exception)?

Thank you.

Comment: Post the stack trace.  Most likely its either an exception due to IO timing out, or you have a bug in your code.

Comment: Thanks, I try to reproduce the error ...

Comment: Always use `try { ... } catch (Exception e) { ... }` around a network call so you can show a generic "whoops" message as a last resort. As you learn what exceptions can get thrown you can improve the error handling. The exceptions will depend on whether you're using HttpURLConnection or the Apache HTTP client.

Comment: @DaveMorrissey I understand, but there is a way to really detect if connection is available, just for notify to users?